# Help me parse this sentence

Tags: verbs, gerunds, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis

I and my friend have started examining sentences to recognise parts of speech in them. In our discourse, we could not agree on the point that "naming" in the below sentence is a verb.

> The White House website, without **naming** China, promises “to use every tool at the federal government’s disposal” to end trade abuses.

Can you please help in explaining if "naming" is used as a verb or if it is a different part of speech?

Comment: It's a gerund-participle verb heading the gerund-participial clause "naming China" which is functioning as complement of the preposition "without". It's clearly a verb since it has the noun "China" as its direct object.

Comment: @BillJ I think that is a valid answer, please post it.

Comment: The "primary" verb is obviously ***promises***, and I'd have to say ***naming*** isn't exactly *much* of a verb. Sure, you could replace it with a different gerund/noun, such as *without **warning*** (feasibly with an "object", as in *without warning **anyone***), but since the syntax would be exactly the same with an "ordinary" noun such as *without **fanfare***, it's not obvious to me that categorisation as a "verb" is particularly useful.

Comment: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/02/      .In Purdue lab it does not say that participles can be used as verbs, doesn't they

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is a good reason, in fact, if you look at it closely. It tells you how you can modify it. Note the ungrammatical "*without the sepcific naming China*", showing that *naming* is not a noun here.

Comment: You'll see that different people here can't agree either. The CGEL analysis given by BillJ is the one many subscribe to. I'd agree it's a more verby than nouny ing-form.

Comment: Yes, of course it's a verb, not a noun, since it's denoting an action And of course, unlike verbs, nouns don't take direct objects. Moreover, it can be modified by an adverb, as in "without categorically/ definitely/  naming China.

Comment: @BillJ I agree, of course, with almost everything you say. But I'm surprised that you say that about verbs -  that they denote actions What about verbs like *endure* or nouns like *fight*?

Answer (score 3):

Verbs often take Direct Objects. Nouns never do. Instead, the semantically comparable string must appear within a preposition phrase, usually one using the preposition *of*:

- they massacre [the civilians] (verb *massacre* taking direct object)
- the massacre [of the civilians] (noun *massacre* taking an *of* preposition phrase)

Verbs can be premodified by adverbs. Nouns never can. Nouns can be premodified by adjectives. Verbs never can:

- the gentle sway
- *the gently sway (adverb premodifying noun - ungrammatical)
- gently swayed
- *gentle swayed (adjective premodifying verb - ungrammatical)

**The Original Poster's example**

> The White House website, without **naming** China, promises to ...

Here we see *China* appearing as the Direct Object of the verb *naming*. Notice that we cannot put *China* within an *of*-preposition phrase here:

- *The White House website, without naming of China, promises to ... (ungrammatical)

We can further see that if we want to premodify the word *naming* we must use an adverb. We cannot use an adjective:

- without directly naming China (adverb *directly*)
- *without direct naming China (adjective *direct* - ungrammatical)

This data shows that the word *naming* is a verb in the Original Poster's example, not an adjective.